# Remove whitespace around own environment

Tags: spacing, environments

Does anyone know how to remove the whitespace which is created by TeX everytime I use my own created environment?  I tried the tricks with \ignorespaces and \ignorespacesafterend but that doesn't seem to work.  I want to make use of labels to cross-reference to included code parts later on, and I have a feeling that this labeling issue might be responsible for the white-space I'm generating?  Thanks in advance.

```
\document{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcounter{codeexcerptcounter}
\newcommand{\CEN}{Code excerpt~\thecodeexcerptcounter}

\newenvironment{codeexcerpt}[1][]{
\refstepcounter{codeexcerptcounter}%
}{%
}

\newcommand{\addcodeexcerpt}[1][]%
{\begin{center}
\begin{codeexcerpt}
#1
\end{codeexcerpt}
\end{center}}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

Here goes some explanation.

\addcodeexcerpt[\label{codeex:first}]
\lstinputlisting[title=\CEN: Mirror.java]{code/Mirror.java}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which space do you mean in particular? The vertical space generated by the `center` environment?

Comment: Instead of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`, use `\begingroup\centering` and `\endgroup` respectively.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks, this already reduces the amount of whitespace a little.  But still, the space above the environment is considerably large.  Ideally, it would just be something of the size of a normal linebreak, now it's about 3 times this size.

Answer (score 6):

You are *adding* lots of space, so just don't add it. For example

```
\newenvironment{codeexcerpt}[1][]{
\refstepcounter{codeexcerptcounter}%
}{%
}
```

should be

```
\newenvironment{codeexcerpt}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{codeexcerptcounter}%
}{%
}
```

to avoid adding a space at the start of the environment.

also in

```
\newcommand{\addcodeexcerpt}[1][]%
{\begin{center}
\begin{codeexcerpt}
#1
\end{codeexcerpt}
\end{center}}%


\addcodeexcerpt[\label{codeex:first}]
```

The content of the displayed `codeexcerpt` environment is just `\label{codeex:first}` which is no visible output and will just look like vertical space on the page.

So something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcounter{codeexcerptcounter}
\newcommand{\CEN}{Code excerpt~\thecodeexcerptcounter}



\newcommand{\addcodeexcerpt}[2][]%
{\par\refstepcounter{codeexcerptcounter}#1#2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

Here goes some explanation.

\addcodeexcerpt[\label{codeex:first}]
{\lstinputlisting[title=\CEN: Mirror.java]{xxx.txt}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, David!  This seems to have solved the issue.  I typically don't create my own environments so wasn't aware of this.